# Strange symbols appear when running a program

Tags: fortran, gfortran, mesh, fortran90

I have a simple Fortran program that read data froma a text file containing mesh data of an object. It uses a module named `mesh` where are the functions to read the file and put the data in a `mesh_container` variable

This is the code:

```
program prueba2
 use mesh
 ! prueba leyendo un archivo mesh .msh
 TYPE(mesh_container) :: meshs
 Character(len=40) :: file
 print *, 'Nombre del archivo'
 read *, file
 meshs = load_mesh(file)

 print *, 'Ahora vamos a esportarlo'

 call export_mesh('nuevo.msh',meshs)
 ! meshs es la variables con los mesh

 !call build_solid_faces(meshs)

 print *, 'Fino, ojala aiga servido'
end program prueba2
```

When run this show the result for the `cubito.msh`:

```
$ gfortran -o prueba1a constants.f90 mesh.f90 prueba1.f90
$ ./prueba1a
 Introduzca el archivo .msh que quiere leer
cubito.msh
Mesh version: 2.2
 Mesh file loaded successfully.
 - Read 14 nodes
 - Read 24 faces
 - Read 12 lines
 - Read 24 solids
 Ahora vamos a esportarlo
 Fino, ojala aiga servido, vea el archivo nuevo.msh
```

But when I add other modules, compile and run again appear this

```
$ gfortran constants.f90 linalg.f90 aux.f90 mesh.f90 prueba2.f90
$ ./a.out
 Nombre del archivo
cubito.msh
 Could not open mesh file cubito.mshAhora vamos a esportarlonuevo.mshFino, ojala aiga servidoD�;�O�����l����b����a�������D����l���������������`����H�������D����l~����!
```

[Screenshoot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG3X0.png)

I don't knew why these symbols appear and the program can't recognize the file `cubito.msh`

But when I type a nonexistent I get this:

```
$ ./a.out
 Nombre del archivo
c
 Unrecognized mesh file extension!
```

This files are in my [Github repository](https://github.com/vicmans/mi-primer-fortran), the `prueba1` is in the root of repository and `prueba2` in the `test` folder.

Comment: Without knowing what `load_mesh` is, this question cannot be answered sensibly.  We really need a [mcve].

Comment: @g.z. Please do not make all titles short at all cost and think twice about the title you propose. A correct title is very important. Your edit should have been rejected. The symbols appear when running the program, not when compiling.